# jQueryUI - Multiple sliders on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am trying to have multiple jQuery ui sliders on a single page. I have looked at a bunch of examples and still don't understand why I can't get it to work. Here is my code.

HTML

```
  <div class='eigenvalue'>
    <div class="slidername">Eigenvector 1</div>
    <div id='s1' class="slider"></div>
    <div id='r1'  class="slider-result">0</div> 
  </div>
  <div class='eigenvalue'>
    <div class="slidername">Eigenvector 2</div>
    <div id='s1' class="slider"></div>
    <div id='r1'  class="slider-result">0</div> 
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
  $('.eigenvalue').each(function(){
    $( this).('#s1').empty().slider({
       animate: true,
       range: "min",
       value: 0,
       min: -5,
       max: 5,
       step: 0.1,
       slide: function( event, ui ) {
         $( this ).('#r1').html( ui.value );
       },
      change: function(event, ui) {

        //Functionality 
       }
    });
  });
});
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: First, ids in html docs are expected to be unique.  It appears that you have 2 divs that share the 'eigenvalue' id.  Not sure what a browser does with that.  One fix is to convert eigenvalue to a class, and do your jquery selection based on the classname, not on the id.

Comment: `$( this).('#s1').empty().slider` seems not correct. Do you mean by `$(this).find('#s1').empty().slider`?

Comment: @TrueWheel, as Cheeso mentions in the comment, you can not have an id used more than once.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Cheeso too. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some of the comments below the problem is identified - I needed to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find)

Following is the correct javascript code:

```
$(function(){
  $('.eigenvalue').each(function(){
    $( this).find('#s1').empty().slider({
      animate: true,
      range: "min",
      value: 0,
      min: -5,
      max: 5,
      step: 0.1, //this gets a live reading of the value and prints it on the page
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).find('#r1').html( ui.value );
      },
      change: function(event, ui) {
      }
    });
  });
});
```